# How to get return type from Python script

Tags: python, jenkins, exitstatus

I have the following code saved as `some_file.py`:

```
def some_function(num):
    return int(num) + 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    val = some_function(sys.argv[1])
```

When I run the script like:

```
some_file.py 10
```

I want to catch the return value.
I tried this approach, unsuccessfully:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        val = some_function(sys.argv[1])
        sys.exit(val)
```

Comment: How are you viewing the result? It will be in the variable `$?`

Comment: I don't quite understand - why do you expect the overall script to have a "return value"? What do you want to do with it? Are you just trying to *see* a result? Or do you want some other program to *know what happened* when the script ran?

Comment: Yes i want it in some variable cause finally i want to run this script from Jenkins and use this variable

Comment: The python script needs `#!/usr/bin/python` at the beginning if you want to run it without writing `python some_file.py`

Comment: `RESULT=$(python some_file.py 10)` would work in a shell script if you simply printed the value, but Jenkins has its own way of capturing stdout

Comment: @OneCricketeer That won't work. That captures the standard output of the process, not the exit status.

Comment: @Barmar Right, but I think printing val would work better than exiting with it

Comment: Since the question is apparently specifically about *how to use the value from Jenkins*, you should edit to make that explicit.

Answer (score 2):

The exit code is put in `$?`

```
python some_file.py 10
echo $?
```

will print `11`

Exit codes are a limited mechanism, it only allows values from 0 to 255. Usually it's more appropriate to capture the output.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    val = some_function(sys.argv[1])
    print(val)
```

then you can use

```
somevariable=$(python some_file.py 10)
echo "$somevariable"
```

Comment: Where to put this $ in sys.exit(val) ?

Comment: You don't, you use it in the shell, that's where the exit value is stored.

Comment: Is it possible also to run it this way from Jenkins Post Build Script ?

Comment: I don't know Jenkins.